# Android fatal exception: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

I have read similar questions about this problem and tried to find a solution but I have not figure out what is the reason in my case. My program's code rough is below :

```
public class ReportSystem extends Activity implements SensorEventListener , Runnable{ 

    ReportLocation reportObj = new ReportLocation(this); //my other class
    Thread thread_send = new Thread(this);

    Handler handler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message message) {    
            msg.setText("---"));
        }
    };

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){ 
    //something...
    }

    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){ 

        if(event.values[0] > 10)
            thread_send.start(); // thread is started..
    }

    public void run(){

        reportObj.send(); //connect with server and send data by the help of RepotLocation class' send function
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }
}//end class
```

What should I do to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public void run(){
    Looper.prepare();
    reportObj.send();
    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    Looper.loop();
}
```